# PHP: How to change Select to get associative array instead of multidimensional array (working code)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am new to PHP and **MySQLi** hope someone can help me with this.

I currently use the following to select the corresponding value (`"content"`) for a list of IDs (`$IDs`) which works so far. 
However, this is over-complicating things as it returns a multidimensional array (I hope that's the correct term).

**Is there a way to simplify the result so that I just get one array in total** with the tID and content for each item ?

**My PHP:**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT tID, en FROM Main WHERE tID IN(" . $IDs . ") ORDER BY tID");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $tID);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($arrTranslations = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $translations[] = array("tID" => $arrTranslations["tID"], "content" => $arrTranslations["en"]);
}
var_dump($translations);
```

**Example result:**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["tID"]=>
    int(1)
    ["content"]=>
    string(6) "Value1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["tID"]=>
    int(2)
    ["content"]=>
    string(6) "Value2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["tID"]=>
    int(3)
    ["content"]=>
    string(6) "Value3"
  }
}
```

Many thanks in advance,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could do something like this as there are only 2 items in the result set and if `tID` is unique.

```
while($arrTranslations = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $translations[$arrTranslations["tID"]] = $arrTranslations["en"];
}
```

Which should generate

```
array(3) 
  [1]=>"Value1"
  [2]=>"Value2"
  [3]=>"Value3"
```

Comment: This is perfect - exactly what I needed here. Thanks a lot ! :)